# Process single Thymeleaf fragment with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my Spring Boot application, I need to process a single Thymeleaf Fragment to get its rendered HTML output.

I'm injecting

```
@Autowired
private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
```

and then try to

```
Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("key", value);

String html = this.templateEngine.process("fragments/foo :: bar(key=${key})", context);
```

with `foo.html` located in `src/main/resources/templates/fragments`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head></head>
<body>
...

<th:block th:fragment="bar(key)">
    <!-- doing fancy stuff with key... -->
</th:block>

...
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't change any autoconfigured values of Thymeleaf.

Running this code, I get the following exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "fragments/foo :: bar(key=${key})", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:924) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:898) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    ...
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? The whole stuff gets working if I create a file `src/main/resources/templates/fragments/test.html` with simply the content

```
<div th:replace="fragments/foo :: bar(key=${key})"></div>
```

and process it via

```
String html = this.templateEngine.process("fragments/test", context);
```

That would be a possible solution, but seems a bit hackish to me...

Comment: Is there bookings.html in fragments directory?

Comment: @KenBekov: The first posted version contained a wrong stacktrace, I've corrected it to match my minimal working example of the problem. But yes, the required file `foo.html` from the example is located in the directory `fragments`. It gets resolved by the hackish solution with the `test.html` file only containg the `div` element.

Comment: Can you successfully render a template fragment that doesn't have parameters? I'm thinking maybe the parameter goes in the context.

Comment: No, I can't. I've got a fragment `success` in file `util.html` placed in `fragments`, the call `this.templateEngine.process("fragments/util :: success", context);` is producing the same error message as before.

Comment: Is your code inside controller or anywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Ken's answer works, but I did it in a simpler way :

```
templateEngine.process("nameTemplate", context, new DOMSelectorFragmentSpec("DOM selector"));
```

There are other ways to filter the processed template, documented [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/fragment/IFragmentSpec.html)

Answer (score 1):

`SpringTemplateEngine` does not parse fragments. So, template name should not contain fragment declaration. To process fragment you have to use another overloaded `SpringTemplateEngine.process()` method, and resolve fragment manually:

```
Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("key", value);
ProcessingContext processingContext = new ProcessingContext(context);

StandardFragment fragmentSpec = 
    StandardFragmentProcessor.computeStandardFragmentSpec(templateEngine.getConfiguration(),
         processingContext, "fragments/foo :: #bar", "SpringStandard", "fragment");

String html = templateEngine.process("fragments/foo", 
    context, fragmentSpec.getFragmentSpec());
```

Actually, I didn't use `<th:block>` for fragment. My fragment looks like following:

```
<body>
...

   <div id="bar" th:remove="tag">
       <!-- doing fancy stuff with key... -->
       <span th:text="${key}"></span>
   </div>

...
</body>
```

And as you noted, I selected this fragment by `#bar` div's id.

Comment: I've tried your code, it's not crashing anymore. But `html` contains only an empty String after processing... Do you have any guess, where my fault could be?

Comment: Because template engine can not find `fragment`. Actually, I don't know yet, how to select fragment, but I doing another way. Answer updated.

Comment: The solution just works in my MWE, in my real project it parses the whole html file and fails to assert other fragments preconditions. Furthermore, it's not my designated solution: I think there must be a solution to resolve/process the template String. Spring Boot does this from Controllers (e.g. for AJAX calls). I just don't know how to find out, how it is done by Spring...

Comment: Controller never use Thymeleaf engine directly. It always works throw ViewResolver. Even in case of Ajax queries. I think, you should do same way.

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try... Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this one for a while in Thymeleaf 3 and couldn't find any answers while searching. For anyone else who runs into this, it's changed in TL 3. Now you use a `Set<String>` of parameters, which isn't documented anywhere, but works like this:

```
final Set<String> params = new HashSet<>();
params.add("/dashboard-fragment");
params.add("list");
final String result = engine.process("/dashboard-fragment", params, context);
```

This is equivalent to using the `/dashboard-fragment :: list` fragment specification. It works!

When Java 9 finally comes out you could reduce this to a single line using `Set.of()` factory method I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

With Thymeleaf 3.0.6 this is very easy. I did not find a direct answer so I'm enclosing mine.
I have one file with fragments (`myFragments.html`):

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<div th:fragment="firstFragment">
    <p th:text="${message}"></p>
</div>
<div th:fragment="secondFragment">
    <p th:text="${message}"></p>
</div>
</html>
```

And I can use this fragments to generate HTML output in Java code like that:

```
 import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
 import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
 import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
 import java.util.Set;

 @Service
 public ContentBuildService {
 @Autowired
 private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

     private String buildContent(String myMessage) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("message", myMessage);
        Set<String> fragmentsSelectors = 
                 Sets.newHashSet("firstFragment");

        return templateEngine.process("myFragments",fragmentsSelectors, context);
    }
}
```

I'm using Guava library to create HashSet but you can off course create simple `new HashSet()` and add element with fragment name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring 3.2.0. The above answers, especially `user2959589` helped me out enough for me to make the following:

```java
   private final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

   private String renderFragment(String templateName, String fragmentName, ModelMap model) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(model);
        final Set<String> params = new HashSet<>();
        //        params.add(templateName);
        params.add(fragmentName);

        return templateEngine.process(templateName, params, context);
    }
```

Note that the `params.add(templateName)` is commented out - for me it didn't make any difference if it was there or not.

This code allows you to pass a model down as well, you don't need to add the parameters into the fragmentname (eg: `fragment/block :: myFragment(...)`)

Call this way:

```java
   ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
   model.addAttribute("fragmentVars", "vars");

   String html = renderFragment("/fragments/blocks", "myFragment", model);
```

I suppose you could modify the renderFragment to take the unaltered `/fragments/block :: myFragment` and place the right parts in the correct place, but this is as far as I needed to go.